# Search on a Custom Page Template WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a custom page template for WordPress which is working just fine for a specific category-type listing.

https://my-domain.com/my-custom-page/

Now I want to add a search field as well on the same page but when we have a query parameter s, the page shows "Page not Found" instead of executing that custom template.

https://my-domain.com/my-custom-page/?s=my-search-text

I know the s is a reserved query parameter, is there any way I can achieve it?

I have another search on the page on the blog, which is working just fine.

https://my-domain.com/blog/
https://my-domain.com/blog/s=my-search-text

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can display a form on a different page, but the form action must be against the base url.

> `https://my-domain.com/?s=my-search-text`

You can specify the action attribute `action="<?php esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"`

```
<form action="<?php esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" method="GET">

  // ...

</form>
```

- Learn more about forms @ https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp